# Laravel Mail tagging

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailgun

I want to set some tags to my mail before sending it. I prepared templates, data, and so on, but how I can define that field for mailing service provider (such as mailgun) to tag my mail? Here is what I have so far:

```
    $messageData = array(
        'email' => 'clientmail@domain.xx',
        'name' => 'My Client Name',
        'subject' => 'My subject',
        'tags' => array('my_tag1', 'my_tag1')
    );
    Mail::queue($emailTemplate, ['data' => $templateBody], function ($message) use ($messageData) {
        $message->to($messageData['email'], $messageData['name'])
            ->subject($messageData['subject']);
            //->embedSomehow('o:tag', $messageData['tags']) <- there is the problem
    });
```

Comment: mailgun tags is a vendor-specific feature. If you want to use it this way, you'd need to extend [Mail::Message](https://github.com/illuminate/mail/blob/master/Message.php) to carry these tags and then use it in the transport when it builds the API request.

Comment: @AlexBlex There is no some array I can fill to be appended to message body?

Answer (score 2):

This field `o:tag` (and many others) goes to header part. To set header value while sending (queuing) mail, do the following:

```
$messageData = array(
    'email' => 'clientmail@domain.xx',
    'name' => 'My Client Name',
    'subject' => 'My subject',
    'tags' => array('my_tag1', 'my_tag1')
);
Mail::queue($emailTemplate, ['data' => $templateBody], function ($message) use ($messageData) {
    $message->to($messageData['email'], $messageData['name'])
        ->subject($messageData['subject']);

    $swiftMessage = $message->getSwiftMessage();

    $headers = $swiftMessage->getHeaders();
    $tags = json_encode(array('o:tag' => $messageData['tags']));
    $headers->addTextHeader('X-MSYS-API', $tags); // X-MSYS-API is header for SparkPostMail
});
```

This way you can do almost whatever you want with vendor-specific fields.